# Execute module pattern function before declaration

Tags: javascript, module-pattern

I'm using some kind of module pattern as described [here](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/04/20/seven-javascript-things-i-wish-i-knew-much-earlier-in-my-career/) :

```
var Module = function(){
  function foo(){}
  return{
    foo:foo,
  }
}();
```

it can be called with

Module.foo();

However, it only works when the call is made **after** the declaration.

For readability purpose, is there any way to call it before the declaration ?

Comment: No, how would that increase readability?

Comment: Why have a special method `foo` for that, if you want to execute it right away? Just execute the code during the module instantiation.

Comment: foo is not meant to be called right away. I just want the module code to be at the bottom of my single page script.

Comment: Why would it then be above the declaration if it is not intended to be executed before it? Maybe you could show your "whole" single-page script (all relevants part of it in expected order).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wait for the document ready event. If you're using jquery it could be something like

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    Module.foo();
});


var Module = (function () {
    //Definition for Module
})();
```

The document ready function will wait for the document to be loaded to call your function. So it will parse all the javascript before it executes.